# How to do Unit testing in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am a Beginner in Android. I want to write a unit testing code in Android studio. How to run that testing in real device and also how to get the test result. I can able to see AndroidTest folder in src folder.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html specifically with studio

Comment: thanks @Christopher will check it.

Comment: @L7ColWinters will try

Comment: better to see this https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/the-basics-of-unit-and-instrumentation-testing-on-android-7f3790e77bd

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to write Unit Test code from scratch. But if you have learned a little bit of Unit testing basic you can take advantage of IntelliJ plugins for Android Studio to generate Unit Testing code very easily.

**Try this:**
**TestMe**(https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9471-testme)

Auto Generate Unit Tests for source class in Java or Groovy.
No more boilerplate!

**Features:**

- Auto-generate Java or Groovy test code with JUnit 4/5, TestNG or Spock frameworks
- Auto-generate Mockito mocks
- Generate test params and assertion statements

**Quick-Start:**
http://weirddev.com/testme/